# how to set previousvalue attribute in input tag using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, node.js

is there any solution to set value for previousvalue attribute for input
field using javascript or jquery in the browser console?

I am trying to set the value to input field it's working but at the same time, I need to set the value to previousvalue attribute which is in the  tag.

```
     <input type="text" value="" id="test" previousvalue=""/>
```

to set value i am using document.getElementById("test").value="add";

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want `value` and `previousvalue` have the same value you can do it like this (imagine input has `inp` id):

```
const input = $('#inp')
input.attr('previousvalue', input.attr('value'))
```

generaly you can set attribute of tag in JQ like below structure:

```
$(el).attr('attr-name', 'attr-value');\
```

in pure JS you can do it like this:

```
el.setAttribute('attr-name', 'attr-value');
```

Comment: thank you for the response.......   i need to set like   <input type="text" value="add" id="test" previousvalue="add"/>  how to achive this?

Comment: You can do it like this: `const input = $('#test');
input.attr('value', 'test');
input.attr('previousvalue', 'test');`

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="input" type="text" value="" previousvalue="" />
```

```
document.getElementById('input').addEventListener('change', function() {
    this.previousvalue = this.value;
    const { value, previousvalue } = this;
    console.log(value, previousvalue);
});
```